# $multipage no longer working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

All was okay till last hour. Here is the code, I upgraded Jetpack and Super Cache and it stopped working.

```
<div id="content">
<?php global $multipage; if($multipage ) { ?>
<div class="postNavigation"><h1><center><?php single_post_title(); ?></center></h1></div>
<div class="pagelinks"><div style="float:left"></div><div style="float:right"><?php wp_link_pages('before&next_or_number=next&previouspagelink=PREVIOUS&nextpagelink=NEXT'); ?></div><div style="clear:both"></div></div><?php }?>
```

Comment: Do you mean "$multipage" has stopped working, or the whole site?

Comment: Website is running but the pages (Multipage posts) are no longer having NEXT and Previous Page buttons, nor the post title. The above code is not working actually :/